# three.js hidden surface check for CSS3DObject

Tags: three.js

I am currently rendering a scene with CSS3DObjects. The objects would be deeply nested so it would be handy not to render an object if it is fully hidden by an object between it and the camera.

To make things simpler, we can consider that all objects can be approximated to a rectangle. ( Furthermore if it really makes it simpler, they all have the same up direction, and face the same way. I'd prefer a more generic solution though )

Thanks for your input :)

--Troks

Comment: this is called `occlusion culling` and it is not currently supported.

Comment: Thanks gaitat, the proper term helped me get more answers. I guess using a projection onto the far plane could do it, but may be more work than reducing the LOD distance trigger.